# Application is not working in Device but working in simulator in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have one application by using which i will block the foreground application. It means when i am clicking any icon in the home screen it should not start. And my application is running in the background and will start when phone will start booting up. So i checked the Auto-run on start up. This is working fine in the simulator but not working in the device after running the cod file. I am running in Blackberry Storm. Here i am putting my code:

```
public class BlockApplication extends Application 
{
    int mForegroundProcessId = -1;

public BlockApplication() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(mCheckForeground, 1000, 1);                       
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockApplication app = new BlockApplication();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}


TimerTask mCheckForeground = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        int id = getForegroungProcessID();
        ApplicationManager appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
    appMan.requestForegroundForConsole();
        KeyEvent inject = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, Characters.ESCAPE, 0);
       inject.post();

    };
};


private int getForegroungProcessID() 
{
    return ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().getForegroundProcessId();
}

}
```

Can any one help? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea - have you setup permissions for your app?

For instance, your app uses `KeyEvent` injection - something that is potentially dangerous and thus requires an explicit permission from user. In device Options (on my Storm 9530 simulator it is in the 'Options' -> 'Security Options' -> 'Application Permissions' -> select your app -> 'Edit Permissions' menu item) the permissoin for `KeyEvent` injection is named as "Input Simulation". It is also possible to set up permissions for the app using programmatic way (check `ApplicationPermissionsManager` class for this, also you can review ApplicationPermissionsDemo project that is included with the JDE).

Note that it is impossible to simulate permission framework on simulator (simulator acts as if all permissions are always set to "Allow"), so to test permissions you need real device.

Comment: yes, when my phone is started, i set up the permission in the way you are telling. But still  i am not getting the desired result.

Comment: So this is solved? I'm a bit surprised, because your first comment says the issue is not related to an unset "Input Simulation" permission.

Comment: Now can you tell me how to forward a call to another number in blackberry??

Comment: Arindam, please ask another StackOverflow question on call forwarding.

Comment: That's probably because the question is a really hard one.